# Array Fails to Change Value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to compare two different dynamic arrays in two different excel sheets I was able to assign value to the first but for the second one I am getting a run time error 9 subscript out of range

```
Sub sortandmark()

    Dim x As Long, xg As Long
    Dim Lfo() As String
    Dim Greenlfo() As String
    Dim i As Long, ig As Long
    Dim j As Integer, jg As Long
    Dim site As Long

    'Get the main array
    Windows("Test LFO sheet .xlsm").Activate

    'x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    ReDim Lfo(2 To 2, 3 To 5) As String

    For i = 2 To 2
        For j = 3 To 5
            Lfo(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    Next i

    Windows("LFO LIST FOR OCT test.xlsx").Activate

    'Greenville array set up
    Sheets("GRE").Select
    xg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    ReDim Greenlfo(2 To xg, 4 To 5)

    For ig = 2 To xg
        For jg = 3 To 4
            Greenlfo(ig, jg) = ActiveSheet.Cells(ig, jg).Value ' Where the error occurs
        Next jg
    Next ig

    'Testing and highlighting
    If Lfo(i, 3) = Greenwood Then
        Sheets("GRE").Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The second dimension of Greenlfo is defined as 4 to 5, and you are referencing it in the loop with 3 to 4.

Comment: What are the values of ig and jg when the error occurs? Keep in mind that arrays are 0-based while cell indexes are 1-based (in other words, if ig = 2 and jg = 3 that will reference the array member Greenlfo(1,2) and the Cells(2,3). We don't know how your data looks, but that could be a reason?

Comment: Also, def look into using `With Workbooks("Test LFO sheet .xlsm")` instead of the `Windows(...).Activate`